# Loading thumbnail for standard overview, showing bigger image in modal display

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I did search a lot to find a good answer to my question, but unfortunately, I didn't find a correct solution for my problem.
I have a photo page loaded in my Wordpress website. The thumbnails are loaded in the overview to take care of not having too long loading times.
When the image is clicked, it shows up in a modal display, but still the thumbnail is loaded.
How can I get it done, that when the image is clicked, the "large" version of the image is loaded into the modal screen?
Is it being done in php or can I add something to my Javascript where the thumbnail image is switched for the "large" version of that image?

This is my php/html :

```
if( have_posts() ) {
  while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

        echo "<h1 class='archive'>" . get_the_title() . "</h1>";

        echo "<div class='row'>";

        if(is_post_type_archive('pottenbakken')) {
              $album = get_field('album-mug');
        } elseif(is_post_type_archive('schilderen')) {
              $album = get_field('album-paint');
        } elseif(is_post_type_archive('fotoalbums')) {
              $album = get_field('album-main');
        } else {
              echo "Helaas, er zijn in dit album nog geen foto's gevonden.";
        }

         if(!empty($album)) {
              foreach($album as $foto) {

                    echo "<img class='Img' src='" . $foto['sizes']['thumbnail'] . "' />";
                    echo "<img style='display:none;' id='ImgFull' src='" . $foto['sizes']['large'] . "' />";

              }
        }

        echo "</div>";

  }
```

}

echo "";

This is my modal html which I placed in the footer ( and is working properly )

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
              <span class="close">&times;</span>
              <img class="modal-content" id="img01" >
              <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

And this is my Javascript :

```
$('.Img').click(function(){
        var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
        var img = this;
        var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
               modal.style.display = "block";
               modalImg.src = this.src;

        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

        span.onclick = function() {
              modal.style.display = "none";
        }

  });
```

I hope it's clear. ( It's my first question here )

Comment: what is the address of bigger image? I mean source. You need to pass that to modal content. You need to change 

this  modalImg.src = this.src;

Comment: The address of the bigger image is normally handled within php ( wordpress ). So normally the php declares it and now the php loads the thumbnail. If I do a direct link to it, how can it be dynamically then?

Comment: I also tried this in my Javascript : 
var fullPic = document.getElementById('ImgFull');
But that didn't work either. Only the first image is showed everytime on all images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I answered my own question in the meantime with some help of some who was my mentor for a while.

Html / PhP :

```
if( have_posts() ) {
  while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

        echo "<h1 class='archive'>" . get_the_title() . "</h1>";

        echo "<div class='row'>";

        if(is_post_type_archive('pottenbakken')) {
              $album = get_field('album-mug');
        } elseif(is_post_type_archive('schilderen')) {
              $album = get_field('album-paint');
        } elseif(is_post_type_archive('fotoalbums')) {
              $album = get_field('album-main');
        } else {
              echo "Helaas, er zijn in dit album nog geen foto's gevonden.";
        }

         if(!empty($album)) {
              foreach($album as $foto) {
                    echo "<div class='images'>";
                          echo "<img class='thumbnail' src='" . $foto['sizes']['thumbnail'] . "' />";
                          echo "<img style='display:none;' class='imgFull' src='" . $foto['sizes']['large'] . "' />";
                    echo "</div>";
              }
        }

        echo "</div>";

  }}
```

The CSS :

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
              <span class="close">&times;</span>
              <img class="modal-content" id="img01" >
              <div id="caption"></div></div>
```

And this is now my working Javascript :

```
$('.thumbnail').click(function(){

        var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
        var thumbnail = $(this);
        var large = $(this).siblings();
        var largeSrc = large.attr('src');

        var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
              modal.style.display = "block";
              modalImg.src = largeSrc;

        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
              span.onclick = function() {
                    modal.style.display = "none";
              }

  });
```

Dunno if it is the right way to close a post with answering my own question or maybe I just needed to update the main post, but I'd like to just letting know the solution I found.
This case is closed.